# Telephone Call Answering Machine Software

Tags: modem

I have been looking for a telephone call answering machine program for Linux, but I haven't had much luck.  In Windows, I have used CallStation for many years.  You can find out more about it at http://imptec.com/callstation.htm and be sure to click the FEATURES and SCREENSHOTS buttons at the top of this link as well for more information.

I am looking for a Linux equivalent of CallStation where calls can be answered or hung-up on, faxes can be received, Caller ID is shown, calls can be recorded in their entirety, etc.  Is there anything like this for Linux?

In fact now in Windows (I believe this started with either Windows XP or Vista) calls and recordings can only be recorded for like 55 seconds.  I have heard it is because Microsoft changed something with Windows' voice modem support.  I am hoping Linux does not suffer from this.

Comment: http://www.asterisk.org/

Comment: Thanks but Asterick sounds overly complicated.  I am looking for something already created.

Comment: It would be good if you could indicate what type of modem or hardware you have. That will dictate the choice of software you can use.

Comment: The one it is going to be used with is a PCI voice modem with fax.  In Windows 7, it is listed as a LSI PCI-SV92PP Soft Modem.  If this was 10 or more years ago, it may matter, but now pretty much all modems are PCI software modems.  In fact, I think the only chipsets still in use are Conexant, Agere, Intel, and 3Com/USR.  Whatever software is available for Linux to get me to something like CallStation should utilize the current available and affordable PCI voice modems found on sites like Newegg or TigerDirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ordered this replacement modem...

http://www.rosewill.com/products/1164/ProductDetail_Overview.htm

I also found an eBay auction for a used U.S. Robotics 3CP2976-OEM hardware voice modem.

After receiving both modems today, I decided not to try the Rosewill as it doesn't state if it supports Caller ID on the box I received.  The U.S. Robotics 3CP2976-OEM hardware voice modem is working perfectly.  I have CallStation installed on Windows XP in VirtualBox and all is well.

It would still be nice if there was a Linux version of CallStation.  It is just that awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for mgetty:

```
 Mgetty is a versatile program to handle all aspects of a modem under Unix.
 .
 The program 'mgetty' allows you to use a modem for handling external
 logins, receiving faxes and using the modem as a answering machine without
 interfering with outgoing calls.
 .
 This package includes basic modem data capabilities. Install mgetty-fax to
 get the additional functionality for fax. Install mgetty-voice to get the
 functionality to operate voice modems.
 .
 Mgetty is also configurable to select programs other than login for
 special connections (eg: uucico, fido or other programs) depending on the
 login userid. It also supports caller-id if the modem and phone line
 supply it, and can deny connections based on originating telephone number.
```

Note that mgetty will require you to be comfortable with command-line utilities and modifying configuration files, as it has no graphical, friendly front-end. Feel free to google for "vgetty frontend" to get pointers to options for this need (sorry, I can't help there as I don't use either mgetty or any frontend for it).

Comment: Thanks but I need something with a GUI like CallStation.